# Wrong username/password. Access denied. in xampp

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp, localhost

In my system phpmyadmin is not working. it shows

> Wrong username/password. Access denied.

what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your MYSQL is running on your XAMPP control panel and is not stopped due to blocked port....